# Disproving Multivariable Limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I just started learning about multivariable functions, and I was wondering if there is something like Heine for disproving the limit of multivariable functions.

For example: I know that we can approach multivariable functions from different directions to see if the function keep the same value, but is this enough? Is there a more rigorous way to do it? Like Heine was used in one variable functions?

Comment: What is Heine? Is it the property that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if, for any sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(a)$?

Comment: yes i believe so

Comment: Converting to polar coordinates is a classic technique.

Comment: A limit can exist from all directions but still not exist.  There are counterexamples, where you have to spiral in to get non-convergence.

Answer (score 1):

The is nothing non-rigorous about approaching a point from different directions, seing that you get distinct limits and deducing that the limit doesn't exist.

However, yes, it is true that is $D$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, if $a\in D$ and if $f$ is a map from $D$ into $\mathbb R^m$, then the following conditions are equivalent:

1. $f$ is continuous at $p$;
2. if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of $D$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=p$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(p)$.